# Retrieve different information from several files to bring them together in one. BASH

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I have a problem with my bash script, I would like to retrieve information contained in several files and gather them in one.

I have a file in this form which contains about 15000 lines: (file1)

```
1;1;A0200101C
2;2;A0200101C
3;3;A1160101A
4;4;A1160101A
5;5;A1130304G
6;6;A1110110U
7;7;A1110110U
8;8;A1030002V
9;9;A1030002V
10;10;A2120100C
11;11;A2120100C
12;12;A3410071A
13;13;A3400001A
14;14;A3385000G1
15;15;A3365070G1
```

I would need to retrieve the first record of each row matching the id.

My second file is this, I just need to retrieve the 3rd row: (file2)

```
 count 
-------
   131
(1 row)
```

I would therefore like to be able to assemble the id of (file1) and the 3rd line of (file2) in order to achieve this result:

```
1;131
2;131
3;131
4;131
5;131
6;131
7;131
8;131
9;131
11;131
12;131
13;131
14;131
15;131
```

Thank you.

Comment: SO is not a code writing service; you're expected to show your effort (eg, research, code); consider reviewing [how do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then come back and update the question accordingly; in particular, show the code you've tried so far and the (incorrect) output generated by your code

Answer (score 0):

One possible way:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

count=$(awk 'NR == 3 { print $1 }' file2)
while IFS=';' read -r id _; do
    printf "%s;%s\n" "$id" "$count"
done < file1
```

First, read just the third line of `file2` and save that in a variable.

Then read each line of `file1` in a loop, extracting the first semicolon-separated field, and print it along with that saved value.

Using the same basic approach in a purely `awk` script instead of shell will be much faster and more efficient. Such a rewrite is left as an exercise for the reader (Hint: In `awk`, `FNR == NR` is true when reading the first file given, and false on any later ones. Alternatively, look up how to pass a shell variable to an `awk` script; there are Q&As here on SO about it.)

Comment: thank you very much, i had come up with something similar but it still didn't work, thanks